# CSS flex fit in as many as possible without any empty space

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to fit as many divs as possible. Basically, create Russian nested dolls

Basically `.dashboard > .lab > .colocation > .rack > buttons`

This is what it looks like: notice there are a lot of empty spaces that could be filled. How to do that?

[image]

This is my attempt:

```scss
.dashboard {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.lab {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100rem;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: flex-start;

  span {
    color: brown;
  }
}

.colocation {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 50rem;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: flex-start;

  span {
    color: blue;
  }
}

.rack {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 5rem;
  flex: 1;

  span {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

This is what I want: no empty spaces and packing as many divs and children as possible
[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ca7ogLtf/)

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of what you are expecting? Currently it's a bit unclear. Also, add your HTML to the question, not a fiddle. Use the stack snippet tool to update your code example.

Comment: I'm suspecting this might be a masonry issue.

Comment: Yea, also your jsfiddle is on the verge of blowing up

Comment: @TanishqS too many divs. I really really appreciate it if someone could help with CSS

Comment: You got some kind of inspiration? like the idea of "Russian nested dolls" but for a web application since it would help out.

Comment: Also, you could create a live sandbox in which you could explain what you're looking for