# CSS flexbox fit in as many as possible without any empty space

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to fit as many divs as possible. No empty spaces using flexbox.

```html
  <div class="colocation">
    <span>colocation name</span>
    <div class="rack"><span style="text-align: center;">rack name</span>
      <div class="vstack">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rack"><span style="text-align: center;">rack name</span>
      <div class="vstack">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">X</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my attempt:

```scss
.colocation {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 50rem;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: flex-start;

  span {
    color: blue;
  }
}

.rack {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 5rem;
  flex: 1;

  span {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

This is what it looks like
[image]

But I want all the empty spaces to be filled and at top-left we have the label:
[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/np2L1ec4/)

Comment: Is this asking anything different from this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78240762/css-flex-fit-in-as-many-as-possible-without-any-empty-space

Comment: is there a max height to the whole thing?

Comment: @AHaworth no but its smaller, I am just asking to do one level nesting

Comment: also is there a limit to the number of divs you need?

Comment: @TanishqS there is no limit to number of divs. Can you help with flexbox css?

Comment: are you going for ONLY html and CSS, because there can be a solution with js

Comment: Don't repost the same question, [edit] updated information into the old question.

Comment: @Paulie_D the old question is closed.

Comment: NO! Edit the old question and vote to re-open *that* one

Comment: @Paulie_D I've voted it, now its at 0 votes...